# 12.04 BCM4312 and aireplay-ng/airodump-ng

Tags: broadcom

First off, I've read through all of the posts regarding BCM4312 on the forums but haven't been able to get any help.

Basically I have a Dell Inspiron 1564 which I've installed 12.04 on and for the most part everything works fine but now that I'm trying to use more in depth utilities such as aireplay and airodump I'm coming across what I believe to be a driver problem that's not allowing compatibility for these programs.

Does anyone out there have any suggestions how to resolve this?

This is the error I receive:

```
root@Haxornator:~/aircrack/aircrack-ng-1.1# airodump-ng eth2
ioctl(SIOCSIWMODE) failed: Invalid argument

ARP linktype is set to 1 (Ethernet) - expected ARPHRD_IEEE80211,
ARPHRD_IEEE80211_FULL or ARPHRD_IEEE80211_PRISM instead.  Make
sure RFMON is enabled: run 'airmon-ng start eth2 <#>'
Sysfs injection support was not found either.
```

Comment: I have a 4312(LP-PHY) and I've not been able to use any of those tools either.  It's a limitation in the driver, both STA proprietary and the opensource b43.  Some cards work, some don't I'm afraid.

Comment: If no one knows the answer to your question, I think you should try the aircrack forums, there are usually lot of explanations there for different devices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the b43 drivers for your wireless card.

First, install b43-fwcutter:

```
sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
```

Then, download the file:

```
wget http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
```

Extract it:

```
tar -pjxf broadcom-wl-5.100.138.tar.bz2
```

Install the driver:

```
sudo b43-fwcutter -w /lib/firmware broadcom-wl-5.100.138/linux/wl_apsta.o
```

Now, load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe b43; sudo modprobe -r wl
```

That worked for my BCM4312, and after that aircrack-ng worked very well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I followed your directions to the letter and after the last step my wireless card has now disappeared and is no longer working at all, please help

Comment: scratch that, I rebooted went into system/additional drivers and disabled the " Broadcom STA wireless driver" then I went back to terminal and typed "sudo modprobe b43; sudo modprobe -r wl" which seems to have re-enabled the wireless card as I can see my wireless router and connect to it.

Comment: I then tried "airodump-ng wlan0" (note that the new drivers changed my wireless card's name from eth2 to wlan0" and received the error device failed and it told me to enable RFMON and type "airmon-ng start wlan0 <#>" so I did and again tried airodump-ng wlan0 and it didn't work with the same error as previous

Comment: THEN I typed "airmon-ng" and I can now see an additiona listing of mon0, so I typed airodump-ng mon0" and finally I'm getting it to work. Thank you internet!

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, low rank means its difficult to ask questions and give advise.

Comment: NEW PROBLEM. First off I'd like to say that the B43 driver works perfect with the network manager off and in manager mode. However if I reboot/disable monitor mode and re-enable the network manager and try to connect to my home network I can load maybe half a webpage then the connection freezed, it doesn't disconnect right away but it definitely isn't working. I've read around the forums bit it doesn't seem like anyone's found a solution. Help please.

Comment: I've been thinking and porbably the best solution in my case would be to disable the b43 drivers and go back to the sta drivers for regular web surfing and just to swap back and forth as needed. Now I need to ask, how do I do this? becase in my system settings/additional drivers menu I can only see the STA drivers. What would be the terminal commands?

Comment: To enable the STA drivers and disable b43, run "sudo modprobe -r b43; sudo modprobe wl" (without the quotes); to enable b43 and disable the STA driver, run "sudo modprobe -r wl; sudo modprobe b43" (without the quotes).

Comment: BEAUTIFUL! Thank you very much. Now I can easily swap between the two drivers, STA for regular use and b43 for monitor mode

Comment: You can edit the question, instead of describing the problem in the comments section.